# Symfony 3 WebSocketBundle PdoSessionHandler

Tags: php, websocket, symfony, phpwebsocket

That's how I setup the WebSocketBundle:

**config.yml**

```
gos_web_socket:
server:
    port: 8080
    host: localhost
client:
    firewall: main
    session_handler: session.handler.pdo
shared_config: true
```

And that's my **services.yml**:

```
services:
    session.handler.pdo:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
        public: false
        arguments:
            - 'mysql:host=%database_host%;dbname=%database_name%'
            - { db_username: '%database_user%', db_password: '%database_password%' }
```

I can start the server successfully in the console with *php bin/console gos:websocket:server*. But a fatal error is shown up in the terminal as soon as I'm trying to connect to the server from a webbrowser:

**console**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs>php bin/console gos:websocket:server
[2017-02-18 10:38:13] websocket.INFO: Starting web socket
[2017-02-18 10:38:13] websocket.INFO: Launching Ratchet on localhost:8080 PID: 26568
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler.php on line 439

Fatal error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler.php on line 439
[2017-02-18 10:38:16] php.CRITICAL: Fatal Error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 0): Error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Session\\Storage\\Handler\\PdoSessionHandler.php:439)"}


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to set the `lock_mode` option? Taken from: https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/SessionSetup.md#symfony-pdo-session-handler

Comment: You also need to create the needed table manually it seems: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html#mysql